# Windows Server 2012 R2 / IIS 8.5 - alternative to IISADMPWD

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have used IISADMPWD before on previous versions of Windows Server / IIS, but this is not supported from IIS 7 onwards.

Does anyone know of an equivalent or supported Microsoft alternative for Windows 2012 R2 IIS 8.5?

I have seen this [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/asiatech/archive/2009/03/17/how-to-manage-my-windows-user-password-through-iis-web-portal.aspx) about how to copy IISADMPWD from Windows 2003 which looks OK but I would rather use something specific for IIS 8.5 on 64 bit Windows Server 2012 R2.

Has anyone found a good solution for this?